# MongoDB - SyntaxError: illegal character

Tags: database, mongodb

I'm trying to run a sum query in MongoDB that counts all the zip codes in three states, but keep running into this:

```
SyntaxError: illegal character
```

Here's an example of my data:

```
{ "_id" : "80002", "city" : "ARVADA", "loc" : [ -105.098402, 39.794533 ], "pop" : 12065, "state" : "CO" }
{ "_id" : "80003", "city" : "ARVADA", "loc" : [ -105.065549, 39.828572 ], "pop" : 32980, "state" : "CO" }
```

Here is my query:

```
db.population.aggregate([ 
{ $match: { $and: [ {“state”:”CA”}, { “state”:”AZ”}, {“state”:”NM”}] } },
{$group : {_id: null, count:{$sum:1}}}
])
```

I'm trying to count all the zip codes in three states so is this a good query to do this? If not how do I do this?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Which language you are using? If you are using mongoshell or javascript then no need to use inverted commas, it should be `db.population.aggregate([ 
  { "$match": {
    "$or": [
      { "state": "CA" },
      { "state": "AZ" },
      { "state": "NM" }
    ]
  }},
  { "$group" : { "_id": null, "count": { "$sum":1 }}}
])`

Comment: You appear to be using "smart quotes" instead of normal double-quote characters.

Comment: This a mongo shell

Comment: You were right about the smart quotes (i didn't notice that) but now the query outputs nothing

Comment: Use `$or` instead of `$and`. Just copy and paste the above one.

Comment: I think this worked, so thanks!

Answer (score 12):

If you are using CLI, try tilt (`) instead of double quotes ("). Give it a try. Happy coding !!!

Answer (score 2):

Credit goes to [Ashh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7510657/ashh).

If you are using mongoshell or javascript then no need to use inverted commas, it should be:

```
db.population.aggregate([ { "$match": { "$or": [ { "state": "CA" }, { "state": "AZ" }, { "state": "NM" } ] }}, { "$group" : { "_id": null, "count": { "$sum":1 }}} ])
```

Answer (score 2):

Following on from JohnnyHK and Geekbro's answers, if you have used a word processor (or Apple Notes) to prepare your code rather than an text editor, then you may find it has substituted in 'smart' quotes (") for your dumb quotes (", which look the same, but are a different character that the shell doesn't recognise, hence the error).  As Geekbro says, use single quotes (') instead of double quotes, or use a less clever text editor.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are using **CLI(Command-line interface)** so for this, you don't have to use a double quote(" "), just a **single** quote(' ') will work **perfectly**.

**changes** to be made is:
db.population.aggregate([
`{ $match: { $and: [ {'state':'CA'}, { 'state':'AZ'}, {'state':'NM'}] } }, {$group : {_id: null, count:{$sum:1}}} ])`

*Thanks.*

Comment: Thanks man, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Most of the times, this happens because of copy-paste of query from your local file/editor to query editor/executor. Simply replace the single/double quotes manually by again typing the same. This will resolve the error.